# Select from derived table sql exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to execute a select statement from derived table as follows in MSSQL SERVER 2005:

The problem I try to solve is that there are duplicate rows but they differ in DATE field by seconds but i take minutes into account for example

```
ID  DATE
1   08:20:00
1   08:20:01
2   09:21:00
5   10:00:00
5   10:00:01
```

I want to take DISTINCT values of ID's, and order by DATE but as i order by date I need to include DATE field. So i cant select distinctly on one column.

Derived table query (works by itself perfectly retrieving duplicates)

```
SELECT  p.[SICIL] AS ID, h.[ZAMAN_TRH] AS ZAMAN_TRH
FROM [RF_BIO].[dbo].[PERSONEL] p,  [RF_BIO].[dbo].[HAREKETLER] h  
WHERE h.[ZAMAN_TRH] > '2013-05-27T00:00:00.000' AND h.[YON]= 2 AND 
(p.[KARTNO] = h.[KARTNO] OR p.[SICIL]= h.[SICIL]) 
ORDER BY h.[ZAMAN_TRH] DESC
```

The query that uses the derived table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [SICIL] 
FROM ( SELECT  p.[SICIL] AS SICIL, h.[ZAMAN_TRH] AS ZAMAN_TRH  
FROM [RF_BIO].[dbo].   [PERSONEL] p,  [RF_BIO].[dbo].[HAREKETLER] h 
WHERE h.[ZAMAN_TRH] > '2013-05-27T00:00:00.000' AND h.[YON]= 2 AND 
(p.[KARTNO] = h.[KARTNO] OR p.[SICIL]= h.[SICIL]) ORDER BY h.[ZAMAN_TRH] DESC ) AS LAST
```

This gets me sql exception in Java

```
java.sql.SQLException:  
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2893)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2335)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:638)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:505)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeQuery(JtdsStatement.java:1427)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GROUP BY clause with aggregate function in the ORDER BY clause

```
SELECT p.[ID] AS ID
FROM [RF_BIO].[dbo].[PERSONEL] p, [RF_BIO].[dbo].[HAREKETLER] h  
WHERE h.[DATE] > '2013-05-27T00:00:00.000' AND h.[YON]= 2
  AND (p.[KART] = h.[KART] OR p.[ID]= h.[ID])
GROUP BY p.[ID]
ORDER BY MAX(h.[DATE]) DESC
```

Simple demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ea4c/1)

```
SELECT p.[SICIL] AS SICIL
FROM [RF_BIO].[dbo].[PERSONEL] p, [RF_BIO].[dbo].[HAREKETLER] h 
WHERE h.[ZAMAN_TRH] > '2013-05-27T00:00:00.000' AND h.[YON]= 2
  AND (p.[KARTNO] = h.[KARTNO] OR p.[SICIL]= h.[SICIL])
GROUP BY p.[SICIL]  
ORDER BY MAX(h.[ZAMAN_TRH]) DESC
```

Plan Diagram

[image]

Comment: Thank you it works like a charm. What was the problem with using derived table do you have any idea?

Comment: This is because DISTINCT clause performed after SELECT statement, therefore ORDER BY clause does not find the column Date. In the case of GROUP BY clause engine creates an expression(Stream Aggregate --> Output list:Expr[1004], [ID]), and then sorts this expression